# using define_method and following ruby documentation

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Despite numerous attempts I am unable to create a method using the define_method() and supplying a method.

If I understand the documentation for the Module class that can be found here http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html I should be able to do either of the following:

define_method(symbol, method) → new_method

define_method(symbol) { block } → proc

I am able to use define_method(symbol) { block } however what I receive seems to be a method (not a proc as outlined on in the doc I linked to):

```
class M
  define_method(:hello) { puts "Hello World!"}
end

M.new.hello
```

My two concerns here are: 
 1. Doing the above I don't seem to be receiving a proc despite the doc clearly stating that's what I would get.
 2. I have no clue how to supply a method for "define_method(symbol, method) → new_method", I tried googling to no avail, not sure how to use this form of define_method.

If anyone could please shed any light on this that would be greatly appreciated! :) Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post what you're actually trying to do? It's really not clear from what little code you've posted.

Comment: For me (1.9.3p194), running the line `define_method(:foo) { puts "foo" }` returns a proc: `=> #<Proc:0x007fd3a317ab00@(irb):6 (lambda)>`

Comment: I am only following rubymonk.com which is proving to be a great resource and just wanted to learn more on my own about define_method() and method() as I am not sure I am understanding the documentation, from what I gather from the replies here seems that define_method can both define an instance method while still returning something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`define_method` does indeed return a `Proc` or a `Method` depending on usage.

In the first case, a `Proc` is returned:

```
class Test
  x = define_method :test_method { nil }
  puts x.inspect
end


Test.new.test_method
```

Running the above on the console outputs:

```
#<Proc:0x007fe12104e228@test.rb:3 (lambda)>
```

---

The second case returns an `UnboundMethod`, which is a type of `Method`:

```
class Test2 < Test
  y = define_method :test_method2, Test.instance_method(:test_method)
  puts y.inspect
end

Test2.new.test_method2
```

The above outputs

```
#<UnboundMethod: Test#test_method>
```

This is an extremely contrived example, and defining a method to pass to `define_method` isn't really useful in this case, nor can I think of a case where it would be.

Comment: when I run the first code example I get syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end and for some strange reason I need to put :test_method in parentheses, anyhow, thx a lot, this is helping a lot :D, never thought that calling Class_name.new actually executes the code that is bound by the class and hence puts x.inspect gets executed (now Class inheriting from Module starts making a whole more sense :)), a proc is returned while I can still call Test.new.test_method... mhmmm quite amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining a method in your class like this:

```
class TestClass
  def a_method
  end
  # Store the method in a class variable; define_method is a Module 
  # method and needs to be called from within this context
  @@x = define_method(:another_method, TestClass.new.method(:a_method))
  def x
    @@x
  end

  # And to get a block...
  @@y = define_method(:yet_another_method) {}
  def y
    @@y
  end
end
```

Calling the `x` method you would get something like this:

```
TestClass.new.x
#<Method: TestClass#a_method>
```

Whereas calling the `y` method you would get something like this:

```
TestClass.new.y
#<Proc:0x00000000aebc30@(irb):75 (lambda)>
```

---

The tricky part here is that you need a method from an object of the same class (or superclass) where you are doing the `define_method`, otherwise it doesn’t work. For instance, if you replace the `@@x` line:

```
...
@@x = define_method(:another_method, String.new.method(:gsub))
...
```

The following `TypeError` is obtained since `TestClass` is not a subclass of `String`:

```
TypeError: bind argument must be a subclass of String
```

Observe that this *would* work:

```
...
@@x = define_method(:another_method, Object.new.method(:object_id))
...
```

With an output similar to this:

```
TestClass.new.x
#<Method: Object(Kernel)#object_id>
```

---

I assume that the reason behind needing a method from the same class hierarchy is to enforce OO code encapsulation and privacy (otherwise you could access private methods and variables by passing a method from another class).